# Passing a note into Evernote for iOS Applications

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, local, evernote

I'm working on an app and I want to preserve messages from my application into the users Evernote account (if they select Evernote as a destination and if they have said app installed). Any idea how I can do this locally without the Web API? I can open Evernote by a call:

```
NSURL *everNoteUrl= [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"evernote://"]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:everNoteUrl];
```

But this typically crashes as soon as the Evernote splash image appears.

I see that apps like Mobile RSS can open up Evernote and pass in the selected RSS message into Evernote (with the wifi disabled), so I should be able to do this locally, but can't figure out how.

Thanks.

Comment: write an mail to evernote and ask about api's.

Answer (score 0):

See the URL scheme documentation of Evernote:

http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/evernote-api.htm#_Toc297053092

Seems like you can only view existing content via the url scheme. Why don't you write an email to Evernote and write the result in that post here.

Edit:
I wanted to recommend to you to write an email yourself as a developer and ask the Evernote team, if there are extended urlscheme possibilities, which are *not* communicated in their documentation. And if they answer your mail, you could share your new knowledge here with us. That was my idea.

An idea, how MobileRSS does it: perhaps they push new content via webservices to Evernote, then retrieve the new content-ID and than open Evernote? Or they have a special deal with Evernote, but I don't think so.

Comment: I know that you can do more then just view existing content, since, as I said, Mobile RSS can provide the functionality without using the web API.

I already have e-mail as a delivery location to the users own personal address, and, since e-mail needs to be done manually, popping up two e-mail views would get confusing for the user.

Comment: An answer to your update: I know MobileRSS isn't using the webapi, since, before selecting the Share to Evernote button in MobileRSS, I turned off my Wifi to see if it succedded at sharing. Evernote launched and the RSS item was in my notes.